# Automatically have all checkboxes selected on page load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I can find a lot of code for a "select all" option, but what I want is more straightforward. I want the WpForms checkboxes all checked by default on page load, not when a button is pressed. I want them all selected so users only have to de-select the few they don't want.

I am trying to use this code currently, please help.

```
$(':checkbox').each(function() {
    this.checked = true;                        
});
```

Thanks for any help. I posted the above code into a javascript wordpress plugin but it didn't help.

Comment: In wordpress you may have to use `jQuery` instead of `$`.  Depending on where your code appears, you may also like/need to wrap it in doc ready:  `jQuery(function() { ... your code ... });`

Answer (score 0):

on HTML just add `checked` as attribute for `input type="checkbox"`

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="test1" value="test1" checked> I'm Check<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="test2" value="test2" checked> I'm Check<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="test3" value="test3"> I'm not Check<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="test4" value="test4" checked> I'm Check
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all my friend, you are not a retard ! You just need to gain more experience ;)

You should get checkboxes like this in Jquery and check them all:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    this.checked = true;
});
```

This might help you.

About that wordpress plugin that you mentioned I have to say that you should put this piece of code in a script tag and a html file which has the checkBoxes in it.

Comment: Worth reviewing: https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/  *`$( ":checkbox" )` is equivalent to `$( "[type=checkbox]" )`*

Comment: I know, I just thought your jquery version might  be different !

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery for this solution

$(document).ready || use for apply any function on load page

Solution:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test1" value="test1"> Test 1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="test2" value="test2"> Test 2<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="test3" value="test3"> Test 3<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="test4" value="test4"> Test 4


$(document).ready(function(){
$('[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
$(this).attr("checked","checked");
});
})
```